# How to prevent nesting with magical scrolls?

Tags: magic

A magic scroll is a piece of paper made from the ancient alakadaba trees only sprout in the tropical islands in the pacific ocean, the scroll shows a drawing resembles a spell circle which is used to seal a single inanimate object as massive as a bathtub. I'm thinking how can I prevent some smart alec from abusing this magical storage system by nesting a scroll within another scroll? I can enforce a law banning such practice but people will still commit them anyway, so I'm pleading for a clever way to prevent such stacking of objects.

Comment: But what advantage would that provide? I see a rookie mage saying, "I whip out by magic scroll and I summon forth my magic scroll hidden in it. That's right! I used *two* magic scrolls when I only needed to use one!" and that's the point where the mentor fails him out of disgust.

Comment: @Halfthawed: I don't know but I noticed many people queuing up at the custom checkpoint with tons of nested scrolls... ;D

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> a spell circle which is used to seal a single inanimate object

a magic object is not exactly inanimate. The seal won't seal a magic object, unless it's removed from the magic infused in it.

More or less like setting a flame on fire, you can't.